# How can I set TextView into LinearLayout programmatically in Android?

Tags: android

I am creating a `TextView` dynamically. Here, I am creating a mainLayout in which I have two child layout and I wan gave them weight.

Here, is my Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Layout_second_overs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!--Second textview overs-->
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Layout_second_balls"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <!--Second textview balls--> //here i inflate 12 textview dynamically but not 12 seen on the device while i run the app.
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Code to create a 12 `TextViews` and put into layout.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

for(int a = 0; a <= 12; a++)
{
    TextView first = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    first.setLayoutParams(params);
    first.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    first.setTextSize(12);
    first.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
    first.setPadding(5, 0, 5, 0);
    first.setText("12");
    layout_second_balls.addView(first); //This is my linear layout which id is Layout_second_balls
}
```

Problem is my all data are print into log but not visible on the device.

Please, help me to solve out this problem.

Comment: Move layout_second_balls.addView(first); into the for loop

Comment: Should your addView not be inside for loop?

Comment: put `layout_second_balls.addView(first);` inside for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues

- One is for the Layout Design related
- Second based on the layout design and property you also need to
  handle is while  you are adding dynamically view into linear layout

Here what i have changed in Your xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Layout_second_overs"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!--Second textview overs-->
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Layout_second_balls"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:background="#FF13C7FF"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

In `Layout_second_overs` linearlayout height , Width & weight is the issue.
& in `Layout_second_balls` linear layout you have used `weight`  as `1` so you also required `layout_height` as `0dp` if orientation is horizontal

Now below things i have changed in code

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams
                (0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        for(int a = 0;a<=12;a++)
        {
            TextView first = new TextView(getActivity());
            first.setLayoutParams(params);
            first.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            first.setTextSize(12);
            params.weight = 1; /// Need to give weight if you want equal size of textview inside Linear
            first.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            first.setPadding(5, 0, 5, 0);
            first.setText("12");
            Layout_second_balls.addView(first); //This is my linear layout which id is Layout_second_balls
        }
```

above things are based on the question which you ask

***Suggestion***

Avoid adding dynamic view like you asked . prefer to use ListView, GridView, RecyclerView for this type of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign index for a view while performing `addview(view,index)`  set index for each textview created in for loop like `layout_second_balls.addView(first,index);`

**Code** should look like :

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
for(int a = 0; a <= 12; a++)
{
    TextView first = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    first.setLayoutParams(params);
    first.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    first.setTextSize(12);
    first.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
    first.setPadding(5, 0, 5, 0);
    first.setText("12");
    layout_second_balls.addView(first,a);
}
```

Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this line of code.

```
LinearLayout  layout_second_balls=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Layout_second_balls);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    for(int a = 0;a<=12;a++)
    {
        TextView first = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        first.setLayoutParams(params);
        first.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        first.setTextSize(12);
        first.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        first.setPadding(5, 0, 5, 0);
        first.setText("12");
        layout_second_balls.addView(first);
    }
```

[image]

i run this code in my emulator and i got this out put.

Comment: @MilanGajera see when i run this code on my machine i attached the output.

Comment: ok men but when text reaches to at the end of the device size it not going to the second line. this is the problem.

Comment: hey dude copy my xml code the try to put your code not only 12 but set here 30 and try again and run you app in small device.please

Comment: @MilanGajera wait i am trying.

Answer (score 0):

Your `layout_second_overs` requires all of your screen space - so your `layout_second_balls` is moved out of your screen.
If you want to see your two `LinearLayouts` beside each other, you need to set the `layout_width` to "0dp":

```
//pseudo, simply change width to 0dp

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    .... >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="6"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

To replace this kind of loops you are supposed to use a [RecyclerView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html). It is easy to use and responsive (since your list will be scrollable).
The things you have to remember while implementing a RecyclerView are to add an adapter and a LayoutManager to it.

For your example :

```
LayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true);
YourAdapter adapter = new YourAdapter([...]);
RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.your_recyclerview_here);

recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

If you need any advices for creating your adapter just ask.